# wp_list_categories walker without links on categories that have subcategories (to make a nested dropdown menu)

Tags: categories, walker, dropdown

I'd like to make a custom walker that works with `wp_list_categories` to generate a menu of nested `ul`s using my category, sub-category, and sub-sub-category(?) structure. Any category that has sub-categories can't be a link so it can be clicked in order to reveal the sub-categories (or sub-sub-categories).

Here's what I want (only items with a  should be links):

```
Tops
  Shirts
    T-shirts 
    Longsleeves 
  Jackets
    Hoodies 
    Raincoats 
Shoes
  Boots 
  Formal 
Trousers
  Shorts 
  Longs 
Bags
```

See also this **[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/edadams/pen/xxOJRGj) with the hard-coded HTML I'd like to generate**, ideally with a custom walker for `wp_list_categories`.

1. I need to show a list of categories and subcategories in a series of nested `ul`s.
2. If a given category has subcategories, that category **can't** display as a link (a `div` or similar instead).
3. If a given category does not have any subcategories, that category will display as a link.

My menu system is at most three levels deep, and categories without descendants could be anywhere. The reason I'd really like to use `wp_list_categories` is so my editors have the flexibility to reorder categories. If I hard-coded in each top-level category they can't reorder them freely using WP's built-in category editor.

**Goal: Right now, `wp_list_categories` does output my categories properly. I just need to figure out how to override the code that is making category titles with subcategories be links. I need them to just be plain text.**

I'm trying to make a custom walker myself but can't seem to figure out where it decides if a category is a sub (or a "sub of a sub") in order to omit links where they're not wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say the `wp_list_categories` output format is ok to you and all you need is only to remove the links from parent categories, try the following code (you can add it to your `functions.php`):

```php
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'sanitize_list_categories_links', 10, 2 );
function sanitize_list_categories_links( $list, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $args['sanitize_links'] ) && $args['sanitize_links'] ) {
        $list = preg_replace( '/(<li(?:|\s[^>]*)>)<a(?:|\s[^>]*)>(.*?)<\/a>(\s*<ul(?:|\s[^>]*)>)/', '$1$2$3', $list );
    }
    return $list;
}
```

and then add an extra parameter to your `wp_list_categories` arguments list:

```
wp_list_categories( array( ..., 'sanitize_links' => 1 ) );
```

This regex will remove `<a ...>` and `</a>` HTML tags from `<li ...><a ...>Category name</a>` string if this string is followed with `<ul ...>` HTML tag meaning the category has at least one child and left those tags untouched otherwise.

**Update**

To get the HTML markup similar to your codepen example, you can use

```php
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'sanitize_list_categories_links', 10, 2 );
function sanitize_list_categories_links( $list, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $args['sanitize_links'] ) && $args['sanitize_links'] ) {
        $list = preg_replace( '/(<li(?:|\s[^>]*)>)<a(?:|\s[^>]*)>(.*?)<\/a>(\s*<ul(?:|\s[^>]*)>)/',
                              '$1<div class="title">$2</div>$3', $list );
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: This achieved what I wanted and I've accepted it. RegEex gives me a headache if I so much as think about it but this is a really smart way to avoid having to make a custom walker. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @EdA Check the update, it should replace `<a>...</a>` with `<div>...</div>` on elements that have at least one child.